# Formatting output in Bash for a given set of git commits

Tags: bash, git

I feel like there's probably good ways to do this in bash, but I'm struggling to find direct explanations for the best tools to do something like the following:

- Given an input of string data from git log
- filter commits down to only those between a set of tags
- then format each commit, pulling convention based snippets of data
- output the formatted snippets

So far, I've found that:

```
set $(git tag -l | sort -V | tail -2)

currentVersion=$2
previousVersion=$1
```

will give me variables for relevant tags. I can then do this:

```
$(git log v9.5.3..) | {what now?}
```

to pipe all commits from the previous tag to current. But I'm not sure on the next step?

1. Will the commits coming from the pipe be considered an array?
2. If not, how do I differentiate each commit distinctly?
3. Should I run a function against the piped input data?
4. Am I thinking about this completely wrong?

If this were Javascript, I'd run a loop over what would assuredly be an array input, regex the snippets I want from the commit, then output a formatted string with the snippets, probably in a map method or something. But I'm not sure if this is how I should be thinking in Bash with pipes?

Expecting data for each commit like:

```
commit xxxxxxxxxx
Author: xxxx xxxx <xxx@xxx.xxx>
Date:   Thu Jul 29 xx:xx:xx 2021 +0000

    Subject of the commit
    
    A multiline description of the commit, the contents of which are not
    really relevant for what I need, but still useful for consideration.
    
    {an issue id}
```

And right now I'd be looking to grab:

- the commit hash
- the author
- the date
- the subject
- the issue id

Would appreciate any insight as to the normal way to do this sort of thing with bash, with pipes, etc. I'd love to get my head right with Bash and do it here, rather than retreat back to my comfort zone of JS. Thanks!

Comment: Appreciate the feedback, but the whole point is that I'd like to figure it out, and am looking for some guidance into what is good practice for this sort of thing. There isn't a deadline and this isn't an assignment.

I could certainly start reading a ton of documentation on the very many bash commands available and try to piece something together, however, I was hoping someone well versed could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I spent some time and found a solution that works for me. I'm (again) very much not a bash script'er, so I'm still curious if there's better ways to do this, but this works:

```
PREVIOUS_VERSION=${1:-$(git tag | tail -n 2 | head -n 1)}
CURRENT_VERSION=$(git tag | tail -n 1)

URL="https://your-hosting-domain-here/q/"

echo "-----RELEASE: $CURRENT_VERSION-----"
echo ""

parse_commits() {
  while read LINE
  do
    if grep -q "Author:" <<< "$LINE"; then
      echo "$LINE"
      read DATE_LINE; echo "$DATE_LINE"
      read SUBJECT_LINE; echo "Subject: $SUBJECT_LINE"
    fi

    if grep -q "Change-Id:" <<< "$LINE"; then
      CHANGE_ID=$(echo "$LINE" | awk '{print $NF}')
      echo "$URL$CHANGE_ID"
      echo ""
    fi
  done
}

git log $PREVIOUS_VERSION.. | strings | parse_commits
```

I'll explain for anyone curious as I was as to how this could be done:

```
PREVIOUS_VERSION=${1:-$(git tag | tail -n 2 | head -n 1)}
```

This is simply a means within Bash to assign a variable to the incoming argument, with a fallback if it's not defined.

```
git log $PREVIOUS_VERSION.. | strings | parse_commits
```

This uses a git method to output all commits since the given version. We then pipe those commits to Bash "strings" command, which translates the input stream(?)/string(?) into a set of lines, and then pipe that to our custom function.

```
while read LINE
```

This starts a while loop, using the Bash command "read" which is super useful for what I needed to do. Essentially, it reads one line from input, and assigns it to the given arg as a variable. So this reads a line, and assigns it to variable: `LINE`.

```
if grep -q "Author:" <<< "$LINE"; then
```

This is a conditional that uses Bash command `grep`, which will search a file for the given string. We don't have a file, we have a string as a variable `$LINE`, but we can turn that into a temporary file using the Bash operator `<<<` which does exactly that. So this line runs the internal block if the given `LINE` as a file contains the substring "Author".

```
read DATE_LINE; echo "$DATE_LINE"
```

Once we've found our desired position after the `Author:` line (and echo'ed it), we simply read the next line, assign it to variable `DATE_LINE` and immediately echo that as well. We do the same for the subject line.

Up until now, we probably could have used simpler commands to achieve a similar result, but now we get to the tricky part (for me at least, not knowing much about Bash).

```
CHANGE_ID=$(echo "$LINE" | awk '{print $NF}')
```

After a similar conditional grep'ing for a substring `Change-Id:`, we snag the second word in the `LINE` by echo'ing it, and piping that to Bash awk command, which was the best way I could find for grabbing a substring. The awk command has a special keyword `NF` that equates to the count of words in the string. By using `$NF` we are referencing the last word, since for example the last word of 5 words would be $5. We set that to a variable, then echo it out with a given format (a url in my case).

The ultimate output looks like this:

```
-----RELEASE: v9.6.0-----

Author: xxxxxx xxxx <xxxx@xxxx.com>
Date:   Fri Jul 30 xx:xx:xx 2021 +0000
Subject: The latest commit subject since last tag
https://your-hosting-domain-here/q/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Author: xxxxxx xxxx <xxxx@xxxx.com>
Date:   Thu Jul 29 xx:xx:xx 2021 +0000
Subject: The second latest commit subject
https://your-hosting-domain-here/q/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

... (and so on)
```

Hope that was helpful to someone, and if not, to future me :)

Comment: If you're new to bash, then it isn't a bad way to use bash. If you're experienced with bash, and it works and is easy for you (and possibly teammates), then it isn't a bad way to use bash.

Comment: I've been using bash for 20 years, and do not consider myself an expert, but this seems reasonable to me, if it works. I'd probably try and capture the lines and parse them, rather than feeding them to commands/functions - but if it works and you get it, it really doesn't matter too much - that's kind of the beauty of it.

Comment: if you update the question (or this answer) with the raw data from the `git log | strings` (that matches your 'ultimate output') it's likely other solutions are possible (eg, `awk`)